# Why I am not getting any output here? my code is and can you tell me how to convert rtf to text in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

is there anything wrong i didnot get any conversion(g2w to mp4 or wvc)

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     FileStream stream = new FileStream("E:/dllxyz/save.mp4", FileMode. Create);
     string value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;//here i mentioned mp4 and wmv
     string path = "E://dllxyz/g2mv.g2m";
     FFMpegConverter conveter= new FFMpegConverter();
     ConvertSettings settings = new ConvertSettings();
     settings.MaxDuration = 20;
     conveter.ConvertLiveMedia(path,"g2m",stream,value,settings);
 }
```

Comment: Does that even compile?

Comment: From NextGeneration : `ffMpeg.ConvertLiveMedia(path,????)`

Comment: First, this doesn't compile. Post some *compiling* code that demonstrates the problem. Second, `catch(Exception eee){ trhow eee;}` is meaningles *and* counterproductinve since it alters the call stack of the exception. You could remove it entirely. If you want to log or display a message first, use a simple `throw;` to rethrow the current exception eg `catch(Exception eee) { /* Some logging here */ throw;}`

Comment: and what do you mean by output ?